# A Case of Apostrophe

Tags: possessives, apostrophe, attributive-nouns

I was reading this short article on "A Tour of Edinburgh" when I came to "*The Royal Mile*" and "*John Knox's House*".

As the article had not offered very much details about those places, I decided to go online to get some more information where I found out that both "*John Knox House"* and *"John Knox's House*" are acceptable forms.

My question is, why the one that doesn't use an apostrophe is still grammatically proper?

Answer (score 4):

If the place is regularly called the same thing and it doesn't have an alternate name, it is not uncommon to turn the possessive into a name... in this sense **John Knox House** is a name.  It's a single entity, in many cases, the name is even proceeded by "the" (The John Knox House).

Additionally, in this case, the house with the label "John Knox House" isn't *actually* his house ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Knox_House)).

Answer (score 1):

I think the differentiation is whether a building was named after someone famous, or whether they lived there.

In John Knox's case it appears that some confusion has arisen & people *think* he lived there.

The several incarnations of Nelson Mandela House - from the fictitious in East London to the real in many other places in the UK - however, suffer no similar confusion - the chap likely never even saw them -  & the apostrophe s is never added.